# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just input some code :

```
import urllib
response=urlib.urlopen(“www.baidu.com”)
```

And than the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 469, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 483, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘www.baidu.com’
```

Comment: Does anything change if you put "http://" or "https://" in front of your URL?

Comment: www.baidu.com is not an url.  You need the protocol like `http://www.baidu.com`.

Comment: You also misspelled `urllib` in the second line...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `"http://"` or `"https://"` at front of the `URL`, so try:

```
import urllib
response=urlib.urlopen('http://www.baidu.com')
```

Or:

```
import urllib
response=urlib.urlopen('https://www.baidu.com')
```

*Note: Use `'` or `"` instead of `”`, and `“`.*